# State with highest energy of Carbon atom

Tags: quantum-mechanics, atomic-physics, orbitals

A possible excited state of the $C$-Atom is one with a $3s$ electron: $(1s)^2(2s)^2(2p)^1(3s)^1$.

One can find out that there are the 4 possibilities $^1P_1, ^3P_2,^3P_1,^3P_0$. Why is the $^1P_1$ state the one with the highest energy?

Comment: Perhaps you should look here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hund%27s_rules

Comment: I am familiar with those. Can you elaborate as to how they are applied here?

Answer (score -1):

Ok, let's see.

If we take an ideal model where there's just a single electron (i.e. hydrogen-like atom), then the shell model works perfectly. The energy only depends on the principal quantum number. Means: 2s, 2p have the same energy, which is definitely smaller than 3s,3p,3d.

Now, things become more complicated when there are multiple electrons, but still for lite atoms it works quite well. The states with different angular momentum are no longer degenerate. And there are Hund's selection rules, which are empirical.

Regarding your problem. 2p has lower energy than 3s.
As for other states you mention - I don't quite understand your notation. 1p1 - this is an impossible state, principal quantum number 1 means there is just a single spatial stationary state with zero angular momentum.

Comment: In the excited state the $3s$-electron and the $2p$-electron can either have parallel or anti parallel spin. In the case of anti parallel spin the total spin of the Atom is $S=0$. Since for the $3s$-electron we have $\ell=0$ and for the $2p$-electron we have $\ell=1$ we get $L=0+1=1$ and thus $J=1$ because of $|L-S|\leq J\leq L+S$. These Quantum numbers yield the state $^1 P_1$.